# combine rows and expand different columns in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
df1<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4),
                V1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                V2=c(8,9,10,11,12,13,14),
                V3=c(15,16,17,18,19,20,21))
> df1
  ID V1 V2 V3
1  1  1  8 15
2  2  2  9 16
3  2  3 10 17
4  3  4 11 18
5  3  5 12 19
6  3  6 13 20
7  4  7 14 21
```

I would like to combine rows when the rows have the same `ID`, but expand new columns because the rows with same `ID` have differnet values in each of the variable. I would like the final table to be like:

```
> df1
  ID V1.1 V1.2 V1.3 V2.1 V2.2 V2.3 V3.1 V3.2 V3.3
1  1    1   NA   NA    8   NA   NA   15   NA   NA
2  2    2    3   NA    9   10   NA   16   17   NA
3  3    4    5    6   11   12   13   18   19   20
4  4    7   NA   NA   14   NA   NA   21   NA   NA
```

Is there any way to do that in r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
   mutate(nm1 = rowid(ID)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = nm1, values_from = c(V1, V2, V3), names_sep=".")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 10
#     ID  V1.1  V1.2  V1.3  V2.1  V2.2  V2.3  V3.1  V3.2  V3.3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1    NA    NA     8    NA    NA    15    NA    NA
#2     2     2     3    NA     9    10    NA    16    17    NA
#3     3     4     5     6    11    12    13    18    19    20
#4     4     7    NA    NA    14    NA    NA    21    NA    NA
```